# Crecimiento de log acelerado

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo mi  BD SQL en donde el archivo log está teniendo un incremento acelerado **(actualmente en 32 GB en modo RECUPERACIÓN COMPLETA)** y me complica con el tema del espacio del disco en mi servidor, en dicha base de datos se ejecutan por horas un conjunto de job's (contiene `SELECT - UPDATE - DELETE` masivos desde otra BD) distribuida en diferentes horas del día, **mi consulta es la siguiente:**

1. Como evitar el rápido crecimiento de mi archivo log.
2. Que prácticas debo incluir en mis consultas ejecutadas desde los jobs para evitar el crecimiento en el log?
3. Por lo general no se utiliza el `COMMIT TRANSACTION` en los `STORE PROCEDURE`, es indispensable agregarlos como parte de mejora?
4. Investigando leí que debo utilizar `TRUNCATE TABLE, WITH(NOLOCK)` como parte de optimización, me gustaría saber sus opiniones.

Ambiente de trabajo: **SQL SERVER 2014**

Gracias por su apoyo.

Comment: Encontre algo quizas te sirva para desactivar logs a una database. Suguiero busques mas información antes  de ejecutar:
ALTER DATABASE MyDB SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;

Comment: Estoy en SQL SERVER 2014

Comment: Gracias lo revisaré, como información complementaria mi LOG está en 32 GB actualmente.

Comment: Para remover log ya creados quizas este link te sea util: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/delete-data-or-log-files-from-a-database?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Yo tenia un problema, relativamente similar, en mi caso no utilizaba los logs para nada, por eso después de la ejecución de algún job "pesado" normalmente agregaba una sentencia para borrar el log, si los logs no te sirven para nada te lo comparto como respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: Vamos por el principio, ¿Por qué tienes el recovery mode en full?

Comment: En realidad es una BD que vengo analizando desde hace poco y ese es su estado actual y debo dar una solución al rápido crecimiento del LOG.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos por partes porque son múltiples preguntas y la administración del log de transacciones es algo que no se debe tomar a la ligera.

> Como evitar el rápido crecimiento de mi archivo log.

La velocidad de crecimiento del log depende de 2 cosas: la configuración del modelo de recuperación y las transacciones que se realizan en la base de datos. Toda transacción (modificación de datos o estructura) genera una entrada en el log. Si no hay espacio en el archivo del log, el archivo crecerá para seguir registrando las transacciones. En los modelos de recuperación `completo` y `bulk logged` el log puede marcarse como listo para sobreescribir entradas después de hacer un respaldo del log. De esa manera, evitas que el log crezca pero necesitas mantener un control estricto de los respaldos o vendrán los problemas. En el modelo de recuperación `simple` el log se marca listo para reutilizarse en cuanto se completa cada transacción. Esta opción es más sencilla de manejar y el log solo crecerá cuando haya transacciones muy grandes (inserciones o modificaciones de millones de filas). La desventaja de este modelo, es que la recuperación de información se limita al último respaldo completo o incremental de la base de datos, en vez de poder hacerlo a cualquier punto en el tiempo.

> Que prácticas debo incluir en mis consultas ejecutadas desde los jobs para evitar el crecimiento en el log?

Debes mantener transacciones de un tamaño adecuado y, dependiendo de tu modelo de recuperación, hacer los respaldos del log correspondientes.

> Por lo general no se utiliza el COMMIT TRANSACTION en los STORE PROCEDURE, es indispensable agregarlos como parte de mejora?

Utilizar transacciones explícitas es una buena práctica cuando necesitas tener más de una operación en cada transacción. También debes de tener en cuenta el manejo de errores para que no queden transacciones abiertas en caso de un error y ello haga que las tablas queden bloqueadas.

> Investigando leí que debo utilizar TRUNCATE TABLE, WITH(NOLOCK) como parte de optimización, me gustaría saber sus opiniones.

El uso de `TRUNCATE TABLE` puede reducir el uso del log porque registra páginas en vez de filas. Sin embargo, su uso requiere permisos para alterar estructura de tablas (DDL) y su uso está limitado al borrado completo de tablas que no estén referenciadas por llaves foráneas. `WITH (NOLOCK)` no tiene nada que ver con el uso del log ni optimización, solo permite leer registros sucios que pueden causar información incorrecta y hasta corromper la base de datos.

Por favor, no vayas a dejar el log en el tamaño mínimo porque eso te va a causar problemas de rendimiento hasta que llegue a un tamaño estable. Es importante evaluar el tamaño de tus transacciones y definir el tamaño del log de acuerdo a eso (varía mucho dependiendo del tipo de sistema).

Tampoco vayas a crear un job que esté reduciendo el tamaño del log y mucho menos uno que esté cambiando el modelo de recuperación de la base de datos. Si no quieres manejar el log, lo ideal es dejarlo en simple y asignarle un tamaño correcto al log. Si quieres tener un sistema de recuperación que te permita restaurar tu base de datos a cualquier punto en el tiempo, es importante aprender a administrar el log.

Comment: Excelente información de vital importancia, según lo que usted recomienda pasar en recuperación simple debería compactar el log con el siguiente comando: **DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'basededatos_Log' , 0, TRUNCATEONLY)** o dejar el log a una media que yo crea conveniente a las transacciones que realiza mi BD.

Comment: Exactamente, esa instrucción debe ser utilizada únicamente en ocasiones especiales y cambiando el 0 por un tamaño adecuado.

Comment: Entonces analizaré mis transacciones para colocarle un tamaño adecuado a mi log. Gracias por la información.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes cambiar el [Recovery Model](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/recovery-models-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=A%20recovery%20model%20is%20a,full%2C%20and%20bulk%2Dlogged.) de la base de datos al modelo    Simple

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BASEDEDATOS] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE WITH NO_WAIT
GO
```

y después compactas el archivo log

```
USE [BASEDEDATOS]
GO    
--                 | Este es el nombre del archivo físico
--                 V
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'basededatos_Log' , 0, TRUNCATEONLY)
GO
```

Si no funciona a la primera, debes hacer un respaldo de la base de datos y repetir el `DBCC SHRINKFILE...`.

El Modelo de recuperación simple junto a un buen esquema de respaldos de la base de datos debería mantener ese log pequeño.

**Actualización**

De acuerdo con la [documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/recovery-models-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15), el modelo de recuperación simple:

> Reclama automáticamente el espacio de registro para mantener los requisitos de espacio reducidos, eliminando esencialmente la necesidad de gestionar el espacio de registro de transacciones.

Aún así es posible programar una tarea en el [Plan de Mantenimiento](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/maintenance-plans/shrink-database-task-maintenance-plan?view=sql-server-ver15) de SQL Server para que la recuperación del espacio del archivo log se haga de forma automática.

**Recomiendo** además, leer las comparaciones entre los modelos de recuperación [full y simple](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/recovery-models-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#RMov) para conocer si el mantener el modelo simple está acorde con los requerimientos y políticas de respaldo de la empresa.

Comment: Una consulta adicional, al estar ne RECOVERY SIMPLE va a ser indispensable generar backup's periódicos de mi 'basedatos_log', como puedo hacer eso.

Comment: Me refiero a respaldos de la base de datos, no del archivo log solamente. Ya modifique mi respuesta para aclararlo.

Comment: De acuerdo, entonces para tener todo claro ejecutando su respuesta mi log se reducirá o limpiará luego de ejecutar cada respado de BD completa? o debería hacerlo yo luego para la redución del archivo de transacciones.

Comment: @RobinsonAscencioPeña, acabo de agregar más información relacionada en mi respuesta.